# Load json file content in Node js/Mochausing require module passing file name dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using mocha/node js/cypress tool to write my test scripts and able to load the data of a json file using the following statement:

```
var data = require('../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/ABC_DEF.json');
```

If I have to pass the file name - `ABC_DEF.json` dynamically in the script as follows, it doesn't work.

```
var filename = 'ABC_DEF.json'
var data = require('../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/'+filename);
```

Error I see in the Cypress console is:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/ABC_DEF.json'

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Note: Objective is to read the file content whose file name is a dynamic variable and use it's value to construct the test name - `it()` dynamically. So file has to be read inside describe block as it has precedence over `before()` and `it()` blocks. Hence, `cy` commands cannot be used as they don't run outside tests and `fs` cannot be used as they run only in node context, again which is possible through only `cy.task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to read a file by it's dynamic name and use the content to construct the test name - it() dynamically in the same spec file. Workaround: Has split the code to 2 different spec files. First File with a it() to use cy commands to read a file by it's name and save it's file contents on disk. Second file to read the saved file content and use it's value to construct the test name - it()

Answer (score 2):

The `require` command is used to load Node.js modules, and not to read data from file. You *can* read a file as an object with `require`, but that's not standard practice.

If you want to read data from file, consider using the `fs` module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/ABC_DEF.json', 'utf8');
console.log(data);
```

**Edit**: If you're using Cypress:

```
cy.readFile('../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/ABC_DEF.json').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html#Syntax

Comment: I cannot use fs module as in Cypress, I can only use fs using cy.task and it should be inside either it() or before() functions which is doesn't suit my case. I would like to read the content even before function before() is called, that is this has to be done in the describe block.

Comment: cy.readFile has to be inside it or before. I would like to read the file in describe block as it's execution order has precedence over before and it blocks

Answer (score 2):

I would add an encoding to the `readFileSync`, like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('../../fixtures/TestData/JsonData/ABC_DEF.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'});
console.log(data);
```

If you want a string rather than a `Buffer`. If you want that to be an `Object`, you can use `JSON.parse(data)` to get it into an object.

I just did this in the command line, and I have a `test.json` file:

```
> fs.readFileSync('test.json');
<Buffer 7b 0d 0a 09 22 74 65 73 74 22 3a 20 31 0d 0a 7d>
> fs.readFileSync('test.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'})
'{\r\n\t"test": 1\r\n}'
> JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'}))
{ test: 1 }
```